# Good working example of multiple UpdatePanels via DynamicPopulate control?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Can someone provide a good example of multiple UpdatePanels being updated by a singe Dynamic Populate extender? Is there some way to have one UpdatePanel trigger another to make a call and subsequently update another UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a word of wisdom: after doing more research, it seems the most straight-forward way to do this is with jQuery's ajax functionality. 'nuf said.